# How do i add the render layers node? its not there at all. In fact there are no nodes

Tags: render-layers, compositing-nodes

How do i add the render layers node? its not there at all. In fact there are no nodes

[image]

[image]

As you can see there is literally no nodes even though i zoomed out a lot of times.

Answer (score 2):

In this case, (and anytime you have missing nodes mostly) you have to tell blender that you want to *use nodes*. Simply click the button that says *use nodes* in the top of the workspace.

[image]